# "AssertionError: False is not true" keeps popping up whenever i run tests.py on my django project

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am following a tutorial by Tom Aratyn in which i would test whether pagination works properly.

Here is the tests.py file:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import \
    RequestFactory
from django.urls.base import reverse

from core.models import Movie
from core.views import MovieList


class MovieListPaginationTestCase(TestCase):

    ACTIVE_PAGINATION_HTML = """
    <li class="page-item active">
      <a href="{}?page={}" class="page-link">{}</a>
    </li>
    """

    def setUp(self):
        for n in range(15):
            Movie.objects.create(
                title='Title {}'.format(n),
                year=1990 + n,
                runtime=100,
            )

    def testFirstPage(self):
        movie_list_path = reverse('core:MovieList')
        request = RequestFactory().get(path=movie_list_path)
        response = MovieList.as_view()(request)
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
        self.assertTrue( response.context_data['is_paginated'])
        self.assertInHTML(
            self.ACTIVE_PAGINATION_HTML.format(
                movie_list_path, 1, 1),
            response.rendered_content)
```

This is already a copy-paste code from the book, however, the AssertionError keeps popping up.

```
(m_env) C:\Users\mrblu\MyMDB\django>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: testFirstPage (core.tests.MovieListPaginationTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mrblu\MyMDB\django\core\tests.py", line 31, in testFirstPage
    self.assertTrue( response.context_data['is_paginated'])
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.021s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Thank you guys in advance. newbie here. I started coding only this feb 2020, and im already 25 yrs old. Im taking this on.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'response' has no attribute 'context_data'.

try this.

```
response.content['is_paginated']
```

or

```
response.data['is_paginated']
```

Comment: errors pop up saying "TemplateResponse" object has no attribute of both.